# How do you get the gui to restart? (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

For instance, I want the program to run multiple times without stopping after somebody has pressed the "Please hit to finish process". However, when I do run the GUI method again, only the first panel shows up. Unsure of why this is happening.

```
  import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Hotel {
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JPanel pan;
    public static JPanel endPanel;
    public static JPanel buttonPanel;
    public static GridBagConstraints c;
    public static GridBagConstraints f;
    public static JButton econ;
    public static Boolean openA = true;


    public Hotel(){

        Frame();
        GUI();

    }

    public static void Frame(){
        frame = new JFrame ("Kiosk");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(600,400);

    }

    public static void GUI (){

        pan =  new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        frame.add(pan);


        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Please fill out your name and room number");
        l2.setVisible(false);
        pan.add(l2);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints GB = new GridBagConstraints();


        JButton b1 = new JButton("Check in?");
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        buttonPanel.add(b1, c);

        JButton b2 = new JButton("Check out?");
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=0;
        c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        buttonPanel.add(b2, c);

        frame.add(buttonPanel);

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    buttonPanel.setVisible(false);
                    Checkin();
                }
            });      


        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                l2.setVisible(true);
                b1.setVisible(false);
                b2.setVisible(false);
            }
        });      


    }

    public static void Checkin(){

        JLabel name = new JLabel("What is your name?");
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        pan.add(name,c);

        JLabel number = new JLabel("How many people in your party?");
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=3;
        pan.add(number,c);

        JTextField namefield = new JTextField(20);
        c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=0;
        pan.add(namefield,c);

        JTextField numberfield = new JTextField(2);
        c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=3;
        pan.add(numberfield,c);

        JButton confirm = new JButton("Confirm");
        c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=4;
        pan.add(confirm,c);

        JPanel errorPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints();

        errorPanel.setVisible(false);
        frame.add(errorPanel);

        JButton econ = new JButton("Confirm");
        d.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        d.gridx=1;
        d.gridy=4;
        errorPanel.add(econ,d);

        JLabel error = new JLabel("Sorry you must fill in all the fields");
        d.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        d.gridx=1;
        d.gridy=0;
        errorPanel.add(error,d);

        confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if((namefield.getText().equals("")) ||
        (numberfield.getText().equals(""))){
                    pan.setVisible(false);
                    errorPanel.setVisible(true);
                    econ.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                            errorPanel.setVisible(false);
                            pan.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });

                }
                else{

                    endPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                    f = new GridBagConstraints();
                    pan.setVisible(false);
                    frame.add(endPanel);

                    String hey = namefield.getText();
                    Memory(hey); 

                    int people =0;
                    try {
                        people = Integer.parseInt(numberfield.getText());
                    }
                    catch(NumberFormatException ex)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Exception : "+ex);
                    }
                    Rooms(people);

                }   
            }
        });

    }

    public static void Memory(String h){
        ArrayList<String> Guest = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int x=0;x<Guest.size();x++){
            if(Guest.get(x).equals(h)){
                JLabel duplicate = new JLabel("Duplicate Name - Please refer
       to the manager " + h);

                JPanel dupPanel = new JPanel();

                pan.setVisible(false);
                dupPanel.setVisible(true);
                frame.add(dupPanel);
                econ.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        dupPanel.setVisible(false);
                        pan.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });


            }
            else{
                JLabel nameLab = new JLabel("Have a nice day " + h);
                f.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
                f.gridx = 0;
                f.gridy=0;
                endPanel.add(nameLab);
            }

        Guest.add(h);
        }
    }

    public static void Rooms(Integer n){

     JLabel roomLab = new JLabel("Sorry there are no rooms with that
        occupany available");
        f.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        f.gridx = 0;
        f.gridy=0;
        endPanel.add(roomLab,f);

        JButton restart = new JButton("Please hit to finish process");
        f.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        f.gridx = 0;
        f.gridy=4;
        endPanel.add(restart,f);

        int x=0;

        if(openA == true && n<2){
            openA = false;
            x=1;
        }

        switch(x){
            case 1 : roomLab.setText("You have been assigned room A"); 
        }

        restart.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                endPanel.setVisible(false);
                GUI();
            }
        });


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Hotel();

    }

}
```

Comment: I ran your code. Is there a reason you're re-creating the entire GUI each time? I'm guessing you're running into a reference issue because you're creating the Swing objects and adding them to the frame and each other, then re-creating the same objects all over again. On the second call to GUI(), you have two of every Swing object, and each ActionListener is associated with a different button - but the Swing components are still part of the Frame.

Comment: I wanted to recreate? or restart the gui so a new "customer" can use it everytime while still keeping the data. And yeah it is duplicating stuff and I don't want it to do that

Comment: Given your existing code, I would hide/show the different controls instead of re-creating the entire GUI. E.g. in the "restart" ActionListener, I would remove the GUI() call and instead call setVisible() on each UI component that should be shown or hidden for the start of the next user's session. Coincidentally, to answer your original question, calling endPanel.setVisible(false) in that ActionListener is probably contributing to your original problem.

Comment: Yes I did that just now, setting endPanel to false, and settin buttonPanel to true. However when I clicked on the options for buttonPanel, it gave me a blank screen?

Comment: This is an absolute horrible question and I have downvoted, SO is not teach me programming 101 please, you need to learn something yourself 1st. Any tutorials on swing will not have static GUI components. You don't need SO for that.

Comment: Your are right, SO is not teach me programming 101, however it is a place to ask questions and most of all a place to learn...

Comment: @Duncan I'd check your ActionListeners and make sure you're setting each component back to visible at the appropriate times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cleanly restart a GUI, and make sure that the new GUI is 100% independent from the previous one, the best way is to dispose of the previous one, and create a brand new instance.

The biggest problem in your case is that all your fields and methods are static. This is wrong. You should typically have something like:

```
public class Hotel extends JFrame {

    public JPanel pan;
    ...

    public Hotel() {
       super("Kiosk");
       createGUI();
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
       setVisible(true);
       setSize(600,400);
    }

    public void createGUI(){

       pan =  new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
       c = new GridBagConstraints();
       add(pan);
       ...
```

If you want to restart the GUI, it's then very simple:

```
    restart.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            dispose();
            new Hotel();
        }
    });
```

If you just want to reset a particular panel within the frame, you can remove it from its container, and add a new instance:

```
somepanel.remove(somesubpanel);
somepanel.add(createSubpanel());
```

Comment: also what is wrong with having static methods and fields?

Comment: The problem with static fields is that they are shared between all your instances. If you want to have various independent instances of a GUI (like in the case of a GUI that you restart various times), you can't make your components static. In your case, it makes your code hard to debug because you can't be sure that the previous GUI isn't contaminating the new one through the static variables.

Comment: oh cool thanks! and for some reason I can't get the dispose to work?

Comment: [`dispose`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()) should close the frame. It's a pretty straightforward method. Are you sure that 1) it is called 2) it is called on the frame 3) the frame isn't closed 4) you are not seeing the new frame immediately created with `new Hotel()`?

Comment: I fixed it without using dispose, turns out frame.add(pan) was in the wrong place